# Providerfactory for APP_BASE_HREF token is called before APP_INITIALIZER is done

Tags: angular

I just discovered a bug in our software - pretty sure it used to work, but now it's broken.

Plunkr reproducing the issue can be found here: https://embed.plnkr.co/BNRcQFWGkkEitxjwE7pi/

In our app.module we have set up providers for APP_INITIALIZER, APP_BASE_HREF and ErrorHandler in three different factories

**AppInitializerFactory**

Calls an async load method for our config, which is stored in a json file.
In this sample loads *baseHref* and *submitToSentry*

**ErrorHandler**

A custom errorhandler that submits to Sentry, if config tells it to. 
In constructor config is not loaded yet - and that is acceptable. Something about having to setup ErrorHandler or APP_INITIALIZER first. They had to pick one. Instead we look at config once an error occurs - and if we should submitToSentry - we do.

**BaseHrefFactory**

Was intended to set the APP_BASE_HREF injection token to whatever baseHref in Config was. 
As the Plunkr shows, baseHref printed ends up being undefined - not *myBaseHref* as expected from config.json.

If... I comment out the AppRoutingModule in app.module.ts:52 - then it works.

**Question is... (As I need the AppRoutingModule)**

I guess I'm once again (as with the errorhandler) is in a race condition between setting up routing and initializing the app - And somewhere internally in @angular/router/routerModule they inject APP_BASE_HREF.

Are there any way to achieve that APP_INITIALIZER holds back routing module until done?

Am I just holding it wrong? Is there something in the ordering or similar that can fix this.

Hoping for someone to be able to explain me - have used quite a few hours debugging it myself - and is currently lost.

Glad though that the Plunkr could reproduce it.

Answer (score 3):

*[Too late now I'm sure, but I'll have a go at answering this. Note that although the plunkr still shows the code, it doesn't actually run - like most plunkr examples on SO these days]*

Your provider setup has: `provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: AppInitializerFactory, deps: ConfigServiceBase` and although it's not obvious from the function declaration (since you're not being explicit about the type of the return value), `AppInitializerFactory` returns *a function that returns a promise*. This is important, since the Angular initialization process will wait for that promise to be resolved before continuing to load the rest of the app (loading the initial component, etc).

You also have `provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: BaseHrefFactory, deps: ConfigServiceBase`. But, since this is *not* associated with `APP_INITIALIZER`, Angular makes no particular guarantee as to when the `BaseHrefFactory` will be executed (though it's unlikely to be executed until something asks for the `APP_BASE_HREF`). The fact that it *sometimes* gets executed after `AppInitializerFactory` may be pure luck.

To be clear, providers using the `APP_INITIALIZER` token are guaranteed to be instantiated before the first *component* is created - but this is unrelated to the order in which *services* are instantiated. The dependency between services is expressed via the dependency-injection tree.

Note that the Angular router makes use of `APP_INITIALIZER` itself - some of the initialization of the router happens there. So, it's possible that by adding routing into the mix you change the (already random) order in which things happen.

Another thing to bear in mind is that, although `BaseHrefFactory` has a dependency on `ConfigServiceBase`, it does *not* have a dependency on "an instance of `ConfigService` whose `load()` method has been called". The injector will quite happily pass it a reference to an instance of `ConfigService` whose `load()` method has *not* been called.

To solve all this, I would inject a *service* rather than try to inject a value, as follows.

1) Create a service to hold the value:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppBaseHrefService {
  public baseHref: string;
}
```

2) Modify the `AppInitializerFactory` function to take an `AppBaseHrefService` parameter, and add an extra step to set the value based on the config:

```
export function AppInitializerFactory(config: ConfigServiceBase, appBaseHrefService: AppBaseHrefService) {
return () => config.load()
    .then(() => {
          appBaseHrefService.baseHref = config.baseHref
    });
```

}

3) Give your `APP_INITIALIZER` provider a dependency on `AppBaseHrefService`:

```
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: AppInitializerFactory, deps: [ConfigServiceBase, AppBaseHrefService], multi: true }
```

Of course, you may decide that it's easier to simply inject the existing `ConfigService` / `ConfigServiceBase` rather than injecting yet another service. I'd be inclined to agree, unless your actual `ConfigService` has lots of configuration information and you only want to expose some of it.

---

**UPDATE** July 2019, since no-one seems to be able to get this to work...

Firstly, please bear in mind that I'm *not* claiming to be able to set the value provided by `APP_BASE_HREF`. Instead, I'm suggesting that you could inject something *else* that will provide the value you need.

I've created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4ny7q) that shows this in action. Here I have the following moving parts:

1. I have an `InitializerProvider` provider defined in the `AppModule` and associated with the `APP_INITIALIZER` DI token. This uses a factory function to do *asyncronous* initialization. Because that function returns a `Promise`, no components will be created etc. until that promise has been resolved (i.e. initialization is complete).
2. The factory function above uses the `ConfigService` to asynchronously fetch "some data". It then uses that data to initialize the `BaseUrlService`. More synchronous or asynchronous actions could be added here as necessary. (Async/await is great for this stuff).
3. Components (e.g. `AppComponent` in this example) can inject `BaseUrlService` and use that to access the base URL that's derived from the data fetched during initialization. Since the initialization happens before any components are created, there should be no circumstances in which those components see an un-initialized service.

HTH.

Comment: Hi Gary, I'm pretty hung up with a delivery needed to ship soon, so will not get to look at this for the next two weeks - but will try to revert once i've delivered our current sprint. 
But thanks for taking your time to answer - i am still interested in a solution so I don't need to know the basehref at compiletime - but can configure it at each customer site, based in their wanted internal web structures. 
Currently my site needs to run in root at all customers, and thus seperate domain/port needs to be setup - and not just a subsite.

Comment: Hi Gary
Got the time to look at it now. I can't get your idea to work either - and I think the problem is the same, no matter what I depend on. 
The APP_BASE_HREF is a special variable, and no matter how I write AppIntializerFactory, I can't get it to wait on the async call to the api.
The () => load.then() still returns immediately - and call the BaseHrefFactory before the load has finished.

Comment: Can confirm that this solution unfortunately does **not** work for me either; `APP_BASE_HREF` always comes first for me, and only sees the unresolved value :-(

Comment: @qqilihq I've added an example - and also clarified that I'm *not* saying you can change the value provided by `APP_BASE_HREF`, but rather offering an alternative approach.

Comment: @ankhansen: Please see update, in case it helps or at least explains what I meant.

Comment: @GaryMcGill Thank you for the clarification -- I admittedly didn’t get that point, that your solution was **not** for changing `APP_BASE_HREF`. I'll post my solution later here or in any of the other questions.

Comment: @GaryMcGill - thx for the update. What I needed was the actual value of APP_BASE_HREF to be set. As I recall it, since routing uses that to create links when using e.g. [routerLink] in anchors. And with APP_BASE_HREF being set dynamically, this didn't work. Currently all our sites run in roots, and that is now just a requirement for customers wanting to run it on-premise. If we ever get a hard requirement for not running in root of a domain, I will consider alternatives - but will leave this thread as it is for now. Thanks for your involvement both of you.