# angular app in kubernetes using nginx ingress path

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

After quite some digging I've decided to post the question and hopefully a proper answer will appear :)

**Goal**: to have an angular application deployed in k8s, and exposing it via the nginx ingress with a customizable path AND parametrized routes.
Call that should be working:

```
http://my-url/my-app/
http://my-url/my-app/a
http://my-url/my-app/b
http://my-url/my-app/c
http://my-url/my-app/c/my-id
```

**Problem**: the parametrized route `/c/:id` is not supported. The factory is not called, and therefore the dynamic `APP_BASE_HREF` is not set. Call that is not working fine:

```
http://my-url/my-app/c/my-id
```

There, the `APP_BASE_URL` is not properly detected, and angular tries to load resources from `http://my-url/my-app/c/runtime.js`.

There will be hard and long to provide a full code example, but some snippets will be provided for

### Kubernetes

#### nginx

`helm uninstall -n ingress-nginx nginx-ingress; helm install --namespace ingress-nginx nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress` (chart version: nginx-ingress-1.33.5; app version: 0.30.0)

#### ingress configuration

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "my-app.ui.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "my-app.name" . }}
    component: "{{ .Values.ui.name }}"
  annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
      ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
      ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
      ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "{{ .Values.root_url }}"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "{{ .Values.ui.ingress.path }}(/|$)(.*)"
        backend:
          serviceName: {{ template "my-app.ui.fullname" . }}
          servicePort: 8085
```

where `{{ .Values.ui.ingress.path }}` could be anything like `/my-app`

#### angular application

`src/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

`src/app/routing.module.ts`

The routes we have.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '',
        redirectTo: '/overview',
        data: { title: 'Overview'},
        pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'overview',
        data: { title: 'Overview'},
        component:  AComponent },
    { path: 'b',
        data: { title: 'B'},
        component: BComponent },
    { path: 'c/:id',
        data: { title: 'C detail'},
        component: CComponent },
    { path: 'c',
        data: { title: 'C detail'},
        component: CComponent },
    { path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent }

];


@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
        {enableTracing: false}
    ) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class RoutingModule { }

export const ROUTES_PATH = routes.map(p => p["path"])
```

`src/app/app.module.ts`

Just taking the `APP_BASE_HREF` modifier:

```
import { getBaseLocation } from './common-utils';


/**
 * Modules
 */

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
...

    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RoutingModule
...
    ],
    providers: [
        Title,
        {
            provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
            useFactory: getBaseLocation
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    entryComponents: [ t ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`src/app/common-utils.ts`

```
import { ROUTES_PATH } from './routing.module';

export function getBaseLocation() {
    let paths: string[] = location.pathname.split('/');
    let basePath: string = (paths && !ROUTES_PATH.includes(paths[1]) && paths[1]) || ''; // Default: ''
    return '/' + basePath;
}
```

### References

[Providerfactory for APP_BASE_HREF token is called before APP_INITIALIZER is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363210/providerfactory-for-app-base-href-token-is-called-before-app-initializer-is-done)

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25932

[Angular 2 Set APP_BASE_HREF with a value from a Promise / Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190280/angular-2-set-app-base-href-with-a-value-from-a-promise-observable)

Answer (score 1):

After @aakash suggestion, I have analyzed the `HashStrategy`.

To suuport `/:id` we can use [HashStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions) in the routing configuration `src/app/routing.module.ts`. With `HashStrategy` the, so called hash fragment, will not be sent to the server.

`src/app/routing.module`

```
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true}) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

In that case, the requests will looked as follows:

```
http://my-url/my-app/
http://my-url/my-app/#/a
http://my-url/my-app/#/b
http://my-url/my-app/#/c
http://my-url/my-app/#/c/my-id
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to support path with :/ ? you can use Hash Strategy with router module. That way your extra routes will not go to the server

Comment: everything should go to kubernetes ingress controller.